# SyntaxError: (irb):1: syntax error, unexpected tSTRING_BEG, expecting keyword_do or '{' or '(' の原因を教えてください。

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

**コマンド**
heroku run rails c

User.create(id: 1, email: "hogehoge@example.com", password: “12345678", name: “田中")

を実行すると、以下のエラーが発生します。

**エラー文**
SyntaxError: (irb):1: syntax error, unexpected tSTRING_BEG, expecting keyword_do or '{' or '('

syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting end-of-input

調べたのですが解決方法が分からずアドバイス頂きたいです。
何卒宜しくお願い致します。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

質問のとおり入力したのであれば、ダブルクォートが1箇所だけ全角になっています

Comment: 細かいですけど、1箇所じゃなくて2箇所のようです。

Comment: ありがとうございます！「"」を修正後、無事データを登録することができました。m(_ _)m

Comment: シンタックスハイライトの使えるエディタを使うと早く気付けるかもしれません。